How to align nav element to right of the screen
I want to align my UI element to the right only with CSS.
here is my CSS code.
nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #4E00A7;
    text-align: right;
    
}

nav li {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline-block;

}
 nav li a {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


.roboto-bold-italic {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
}

.roboto-bold {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}

.roboto-medium {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right;
}

and a screenshot of my current HTML doc
Html Document renderd
I've tried floating it to the right, text aligning it, hoping it would go left.

Can you please explain why this is related to python?

Try setting justify-content in the nav rule to flex-end.
Below I've just taken your CSS and inserted justify-content: flex-end to nav.


nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #4E00A7;
    text-align: right;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav li {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline-block;

}
 nav li a {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


.roboto-bold-italic {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
}

.roboto-bold {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}

.roboto-medium {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
<nav>
  <li><a>Logout</a></li>
  <li><a>Login</a></li>
  <li><a>Communities</a></li>
  <li><a>Home</a></li>

</nav>




"Try setting justify-content ... to flex-end" - just end would also work, the flex- prefix isn't required.
